# How to close/purge websocket connection from server side with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, websocket, java-websocket

I am using `jakarta.websocket` on Tomcat and I want my server after some time to close the websocket connection with a connected client. For that, I am calling `session.close()` which then triggers indeed

```
@OnClose
public void end() {}
```

However, I see that the client (who might not be complying with the closing handshake) is still able to send binary messages to the server via the previous (supposedly closed) session. Is this expected? Do both sides need indeed to agree for the server to close/purge the session? I also thought of setting for the session a timeout of a few milliseconds but I don't know if that would work well. Or maybe somehow kill from Tomcat the underlying TCP connection but I again dunno how to do that.

Ultimately, how can I force the session to be completely purged from the server side and thus, make the client unable to reach the server using his previous session?

I am closing it from a runnable:

```
private class disconnector implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            session.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // So far, I have not noticed any exceptions here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to control this in OnMessage like below? i.e Only when there is valid session then respond back. Else ignore that client session.

```
@OnMessage
public void message(final String message, final javax.websocket.Session session) throws IOException {
 for (final Session s : session.getOpenSessions()) {
     final Basic endpoint = s.getBasicRemote();
     endpoint.sendText(message);
 }
}
```